# Android set loading notification for laggy/slow button

Tags: android, button, loading

I have a button that opens up a different activity.
However, the activity is kind of resource intensive, and takes roughly a second to load.
(I have a lot of stuff in the onCreate)

In the meantime, there is no user feedback that the button has been pressed successfully (which can lead to spam pressing and opening the activity a bunch of times)

I noticed that the button pressed animation only goes through after the activity I want to load has properly loaded (which as I mentioned takes a moment)

I believe this will lead to poor user experience, and I want to create some immediate feedback as soon as the button is pressed.

I tried creating a Toast message as soon as the button was pressed, or create a Progress Dialogue message, but they all execute after the activity opens, which kind of defeats the purpose.
I would be satisfied if there was a way for the button pressing animation was triggered immediately and got "stuck" until the code inside the onClick is done running, or a way to send a message immediately.

```
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Initial attempt to create a notification upon button press (doesn't work)
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"It\'s going, give it a moment",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();  
        
            //Attach a 500kb string to my intent (takes around a second)
            intentViewPrices.putExtra("priceData",txtJson.getText().toString());
            //Starts an activity that has to process all that data (also takes a second)
            startActivity(intentViewPrices);
        }
```

If anyone has any advice that would be great!

UPDATE:
After further testing I found out that in my own case, a previous resource intensive task was not quite finished, and in that literal second if I pressed this button, it "queues" it up but doesn't actually work, making it seem like it was the button's fault, but in my case it wasn't.

(Though this isn't super important, my actual code does work fine, albeit with a tiny delay)

Comment: A small portion of the code would be great so that people could have an idea what to do :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your button is pressed start a background thread where your resource intensive code will go.

```
button.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        //don't allow any more clicks
        button.setEnabled( false);

        new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //resource intensive code
            }

        }.start();
    });
```

Does this help?